# Checking if a complex number has NaN

Tags: c++, std, borland-c++

I'm trying to check if a `std::complex` number that is a result of a fourier transform (using http://fftw.org/) contains a `NaN` in either the real or imag part.

I'm using Borland C++, so I don't have access to `std::isnan`. I have tried to check if the number is `NaN` by comparing it to itself:

```
(n.imag() != n.imag())
```

However, as soon as I call the `n.imag()` or `std::imag(n)`, I get a "floating point invalid operation".

Is there any way to validate if a `std::complex` is good; if it contains a `NaN`?

Comment: Change your compiler if it doesn't support `std::isnan`.

Comment: Nawaz: Working on it. But it's a large code base and I have to maintain the product in the mean time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that Borland has its own math library. So if you want to avoid floating point errors, use IsNan from Borlands Math.

http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Math_IsNan@Double.html

Comment: To check for NaN in a complex number, I had to do this hack in Borland: given std::complex<double> n; double a(n._Val[0]); double b(n.Val[1]); IsNan(a) || IsNan(b), where IsNan is defined in Math.hpp

Answer (score 4):

This works on g++ :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<complex>

int main(){

  double x=sqrt(-1.);
  std::complex<double> c(sqrt(-1.), 2.);

  std::cout<<x<<"\n";
  std::cout<<c<<"\n";

  std::cout<< ( (c!=c) ? "yup" : "nope" )<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: Edit: This works. I tried this, and here is the output: +NAN (+NAN, 2) nope

Comment: @dagur: so it did work --- it did tell you 'yup' for a complex number which is a NaN. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, I was slow at editing my response when I realized that :).

Comment: The real output: +NAN (+NAN, 2) yup

Answer (score 1):

From the `float.h` header

```
int _isnan(double d);
```

Returns a `nonzero` value (`TRUE`) if the value passed in is a NaN; otherwise it returns `0` (`FALSE`).

```
int _fpclass(double __d);
```

Returns an integer value that indicates the floating-point class of its argument. The possible values are defined in FLOAT.H (NaN, INF, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Is there `fpclassify()` in `math.h`? It should return `FP_NAN` for NaNs. Or better yet use `isnan()`. If there are no such functions/macros, you may look at the binary representation of your floats or doubles and check manually for NaNs. See IEEE-754 single and double precision formats for details.

Comment: fpclassify() does not seem to exist in the std Borland C++ uses